# FirebaseApp is not initialized on real devices

Tags: push-notification, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Please advice, I'm trying to add push notifications in `PCL` `Xamarin.Forms`.
On emulator `Genymotion` it's work fine but on real devices i have an error: 
**Default FirebaseApp is not initialized.Make shure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)**

`google-services.json` is present in Android project with `GoogleServicesJson` `BuildAction`

My `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
        {
            internal static MainActivity Instance { get; private set; }
            internal static FirebaseInstanceId FirebaseInstance { get; private set; }

            public static int CurrentUserId { get; set; }
            protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
            {
                base.OnCreate(bundle);           

                TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
                ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

                VideoViewRenderer.Init();
                global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
                string dbPath = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath("LocalDataBase.db");

                LoadApplication(new App());

                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().UseWindowSoftInputModeAdjust(WindowSoftInputModeAdjust.Resize);
                UserDialogs.Init(this);
                CachedImageRenderer.Init();           

            //on real devices it return  null
                var app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this.ApplicationContext);

                Instance = this;
            }
```

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/CrossGeeks/FirebasePushNotificationPlugin . It works ok for me on real device and have good tutorial how to start to use it

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after downgrade NuGet package version Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base to 42.1001.0

Comment: Do you have any information on why this solves it. Is there a known bug? Has it been fixed in more recent versions?

Comment: I haven't additional info about problem.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the other way round, I did not have Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging installed at first. But after installing it from Nuget, it works.